# Which is best approach for fast rendering in MVC3 razor engine? foreach loop or giving by Index number?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I'm working on e-commerce site which is based on ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor Engine.
I want to display  products.

for example,
only for 5 products.

```
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{ 

   @foreach (var @item in Model)
   {
        <text>Product Name:</text>@item.Name
   }
}
```

or

```
    @if (Model.Count > 0)
    { 
        <text>Product Name:</text>@Model.Name[0]
        <text>Product Name:</text>@Model.Name[1]
        <text>Product Name:</text>@Model.Name[2]
        <text>Product Name:</text>@Model.Name[3]
        <text>Product Name:</text>@Model.Name[4]
     }
```

so which is best approach for fast rendering?

Comment: I think that both approaches are fast. The difference is in the code quality and protection against exceeding the array index. Foreach statement is better.

Comment: What happen if another Partial view will call instead of @item.Name? Is rendering still fast?

Comment: Is there a performance differnce between calling @Html.DisplayFor(...) vs @item.Name ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing premature optimization which is something that you shouldn't be doing. The second snippet will be negligibly faster than the first but, OMG, that's ugly. I would prefer the code that's most readable. And personally I would use a display template:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
}
```

and then define a custom display template that will automatically be rendered for each element of the model (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>
    Product Name: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
</div>
```

Comment: but i think it iterates whole template.